# Further smoothness conditions on $f$ imply better decay of Fourier Coefficients.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

Suppose $f$ is a periodic function of period $2\pi$ which belongs to the class $C^{k}.$

Show that $$\hat{f}(n) = O(\frac{1}{|n|^{k}})$$ as $|n|\rightarrow \infty.$ How can I iterate to get that the above is true for $|n|^{k}$, Could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, $a_n=O(\frac{1}{|n|^k})$ means that $|a_n|\le C/|n|^k$ for some constant $C$. Now
$$
\hat f(n)=\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)e^{inx}\,dx.
$$
Taking absolute values
$$
|\hat f(n)|\le\int_0^{2\pi}|f(x)|\,dx=O(1).
$$
If $f$ is $C^1$, integrating by parts and using the periodicity we get
$$
\hat f(n)=\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)e^{inx}\,dx=\frac{1}{i\,n}\int_0^{2\pi}f'(x)e^{inx}\,dx
$$
and
$$
|\hat f(n)|\le\frac{1}{|n|}\int_0^{2\pi}|f'(x)|\,dx=O\Bigl(\frac{1}{|n|}\Bigr).
$$
Iterate to get the result for $f$ of class $C^k$.

Comment: Aguirre .... what do u mean by iterate? what should I write if I am answering this question in an exam? thanks

Comment: Apply the formula to $f''=(f')'$ and so on.

Comment: Aguirre So I should prove it by induction on number of derivatives ?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea.

Comment: How would you make the approximation that
$$
\frac{1}{i\,n}\int_0^{2\pi}f'(x)e^{inx}\,dx \leq \frac{1}{|n|}\int_0^{2\pi}|f'(x)|\,dx
$$
And also for the general case where $f \in C^k$?